# Laravel View display: @foreach within @if

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm using the materialisecss CSS framework within my Laravel Views, and I'm trying to set my layout such that:

- if there is only one post available, it is displayed 6 columns wide,
  offset by 3
- if there are only 2 posts, they are both displayed 6 columns wide side by side
- if there are more than 2 posts they are displayed 4 columns wide.

I have the code below as part of my view, but it doesn't like it, and returns the following:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) (View: /home/testuser/sites/lsapp/resources/views/posts/index.blade.php)`

```
    @if(count($posts) > 0)

    <div class="row">

        @if (count($posts) === 1)

            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3">

        @elseif (count($posts) === 2)

            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="col s12 m6">

        @else
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="col s12 m4">

        @endif

            <a href="posts/{{$post->id}}">
                <div class="card hoverable">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/460x230">
                        <span class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</span>
                        <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red hover"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>
                            Created by {{$post->user->name}}<br>
                            <small>on {{$post->created_at->toDateString()}} at {{$post->created_at->toTimeString()}}</small>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        @endforeach

    </div>

    @else
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="card">
                    <p>No posts found</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

I think it has something to do with the foreach, but I'm not certain.

Note: There is probably a far better way of doing this, but I'm currently learning Laravel after teaching myself PHP, so it's not the end of the world.

Comment: I would suggest checking against the posts.count() and then depending on the number. Include a blade directive with the desired cols. So if count == 2 include('....'). With this you have some resuable code (the directives) plus eliminate looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the problem because you're not closing off the directives properly. Try something like this.

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="@if (count($posts) === 1) col s12 m6 offset-m3 @elseif (count($posts) === 2) col s12 m6 @else col s12 m4 @endif">


                <a href="posts/{{$post->id}}">
                    <div class="card hoverable">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/460x230">
                            <span class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</span>
                            <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red hover"><i
                                        class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>
                                Created by {{$post->user->name}}<br>
                                <small>on {{$post->created_at->toDateString()}}
                                    at {{$post->created_at->toTimeString()}}</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@else
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="card">
                <p>No posts found</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! For some reason, I didn't think to just add it to the classes rather than an individual div for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `@endforeach`

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
....
@endforeach
```

The error is saying that there is an unexpected `@elseif` because the parser expects you to end the foreach before.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
   @if (count($posts) === 1)
       <?php $class = 'col s12 m6 offset-m3'; ?>
    @elseif (count($posts) === 2)
       <?php $class = 'col s12 m6'; ?>
    @else
        <?php $class = 'col s12 m4'; ?>
    @endif

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="{{ $class }}">
       //rest of code...

    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes every directive must be closed properly. Meaning you should have the closing tag `@endforeach` after every `@foreach` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If it's difficult. You can try

```
@php @endphp
```